# Divide a string into two at hyphen

Tags: java, string, substring

I am taking a String variable from request.

```
String issueField = request.getParameter("issueno");
```

This may or may not have a hyphen in the middle. I want to be able to traverse through the String and divide the string when hyphen is seen.

Comment: why don't you use `issueField.split("-")` and just check the array size??

Comment: Hi, Next time for SEO reason, i advise you add the language you refer to in the question asked. This is so google doesn't direct people to your question even if what they want is PHP or dart etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use String#split:

```
String[] parts = issueField.split("-");
```

Then you can use `parts[0]` to get the first part, `parts[1]` for the second, ...

Comment: Bah, be sure parts.length is greater or equal than two... or maybe check if it has more than one hyphen or something...

Answer (score 2):

[String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Although [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) will do the job, Guava's Splitter class doesn't silently discard trailing separators, and it's API doesn't force using a regex when it's not needed:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

With respect to your question, here's a code snippet:

```
Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on('-').split(issueField);
```

Some additional bonuses with using Splitter instead of String.split:

- The returned `Iterable` is lazy.  In
  other words, it won't actually do the
  work until you are iterating over it.
- It doesn't split all of the tokens
  and store them in memory.  You can
  iterate over a huge string,
  token-by-token, w/o doubling up on
  memory usage.

The only reason not to use Splitter is if you don't want to include Guava in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.StringTokenizer class as well. Though String.split is more easy and suitable way for your problem.