# Passing Date time from Java as mentioned below?

Tags: java, json, datetime

"TransactionDateTime": "/Date(1457540067076-0500)/"

I have transaction date time to be passed in JSON above format from Java .

What is the format of the "transactiondatetime" above mentioned . And how can i pass as above . please provide me a example to follow if any .Thanks for helo

Comment: That is suppose is a [milliseconds-Timezone-In-GMT]

Comment: you want that long number in a readable format? like Jan 8, 2022 8:00pm?

Comment: You are not clear what you want , Do you want to generate date time in "1457540067076-0500" format ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like long milliseconds with the Timezone following it. The number of seconds since epoch , followed by tz behind UTC

** edits **

```
    Date date = new Date(1457540067076l);

    System.out.println(date);
```

outputs : Wed Mar 09 21:44:27 IST 2016

Answer (score 0):

Java follows timing system called epoch time, which is relative to date Jan 1, 1970. 
More details on epoch conversion are [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Your expected JSON format consists of time and time zone offset in HHMM format.

For this, you need to get time in epoch format for your transaction time.
Also, need to get time zone for your client.

For example:

```
    Date transactionDateTime = new Date();
    long time = transactionDateTime.getTime();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int timezone = ((calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000));
    System.out.println(time + " - " + String.format("%02d",timezone/60)+""+String.format("%02d",timezone%60));
```

You need to modify the example code according to your format requirements. Also take care of sign(+ or -) of time zones.

Answer (score 0):

## Read your API documentation

You should be reading the documentation for whatever web service is sending you this data.

The first part *appears* to be a count of milliseconds since an epoch of start of 1970 UTC. And the second part `-0500` *appears* to be an offset-from-UTC of five hours behind UTC. But this is just a guess. You can only know for sure by reading the doc to identify the parts, and to resolve the ambiguity discussed below.

## Parse

So first split the String on the hyphen, into two substrings, as [discussed in this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965966/642706).

Next, parse the count as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Discussed [in this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19163041/642706).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( countOfMillisecondsFromEpochNumberPortionOfInput );
```

## Adjust

How you interpret that combination is ambiguous. Is the count of milliseconds in UTC that should be adjusted by five hours? Or is the count already adjusted to five hours?

Another ambiguity: Is the minus sign meant to say "behind" or "ahead" of UTC? Current practice is commonly "behind" but some older practices meant "ahead". I'll assume "behind".

I will assume the count is intended to be in UTC, then adjusted into five hours behind UTC by applying a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html). The time-of-day and perhaps date will change to represent the same simultaneous moment viewed as a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( offsetStringPortionOfInput );
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );  // time-of-day and perhaps date will change to represent the same simultaneous moment viewed as a different wall-clock time.
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.